# PHP mail with breaks database

Tags: php, mysql

I am pulling information from a database, and trying to send it as an email. There will be multiple rows of data pulled from the database. This is what my code looks like...

```
<?php
$to = "--";
$subject = "Test mail";
$message .= "This Week's Memo: ";

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
$message .= $row["first_name"];
$message .= (date ('F-d ', strtotime($row["time"])));
$message .= $row["title"];
$message .= $row["memo"];
};


$from = "--";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
echo "Mail Sent.";
?>
```

All of the info mails fine. My problem is, I would like to keep the breaks in. For instance after the title, I would like a break, and then the memo info to start.
Any ideas I could take a look at how to achieve? Thanks for any help.

please let me know if more info is needed. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add it. Concatenate a new line after your title

```
$message .= $row["title"] ."\n";
```

As side note I would suggest you to start declaring message variable and then concatenate the other strings

```
$message = "This Week's Memo: ";
       //^ no dot at first declaration
```

Comment: The \n works perfect. I need to better educate myself on how tags are extracted and entered into a database...

Comment: @user1075004 yeah it does! I'm glad i helped you out!

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$message .= $row["title"].'<br/>';
$message .= $row["memo"];
```

Comment: concatenating the "<br/>" only adds <br/> to the email message. everything is still inline...

Answer (score 0):

use PHP_EOL to work on different OS

```
$message .= $row["title"].PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: PHP_EOL? End of Line I imagine?

Comment: yes, PHP_EOL on windows \r\n on Linux \r takes out the guess work

Comment: This should be the correct answer. It was written using the standard PHP_EOL instead of the "\n" alone.